# Java Garbage Collection and Graphics dispose method

Tags: java, graphics, synchronization, dispose, toolkit

I am creating a game (a Snake Clone) as a hobby. I was looking at the dispose method from the Graphics class in the Java API. When I comment out the dispose method, My animation works the same way just fine with or without it. In the Java API, the dispose method does this- releases system resources that the graphics context is using. Doesn't the Java garbage collection manage the memory of the program similar to what the dispose is doing? Should I keep the dispose method?

The API was not much help in explaining the sync method. But from what I read in other forums , the sync method from the ToolKit class is to ensure the drawing operation (like paintComponent method I suppose) flushes to the graphics card. So is the graphic card's job to clean up any remains of the previous graphics contexts of the program?

Here's the code:

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
            g.dispose();

     }
```

Comment: The Javadoc says: `When a Java program runs, a large number of Graphics objects can be created within a short time frame. Although the finalization process of the garbage collector also disposes of the same system resources, it is preferable to manually free the associated resources by calling this method rather than to rely on a finalization process which may not run to completion for a long period of time.`

Comment: Never ever rely on garbage collectors for system/unmanaged resources. Your GC may not kick in for some few minutes while your graphics stack may be exhausted as the result you will stop seeing graphics while having plenty of free ram. This happens in Java in .NET does not matter because GUI object pools are constrained, i.e. you can not expect to allocate 1,000,000 brushes even if you have 8 Gb ram. The more ram you have - the less aggressive the GC is and this is the problem. I have seen to many apps in .NET that paint "red cross" instead of buttons and images, then come back to life in 5min

Comment: @itadapter is the graphics stack located in the graphic card or the CPU? I heard of a stack but never a graphics stack. Wow, I learned so much already! Thanks for the info!

Comment: The graphics stack is located in the OS - it is a logical thing, for example in gdi.dll on Windows. IF device driver supports certain hardware accelerations then things like brushes and pens may be pipelined into PCI card. But GDI is the bottleneck that has internal fixed-size arrays. On Android for example the 2d drawing is made with SKIA library that is hungry for ram per every brush/pen

Comment: @Nicholas: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#dispose%28%29

Comment: Graphics stack = as in "graphics components", which are mechanisms of rendering of 2d primitives (at minimum) and window-management functions (functions that manage bitmap display in regions). That is what I call graphics stack. Do not confuse with stack segment used for execution of code which is a CPU specially-purposed register (a pointer register used for relative addressing and referencing of temp values)

Comment: @Greg: thanks Greg for the link!

Comment: @itadapter: what do you mean by "paint red crosses instead of buttons and images", then come back to life in 5min? you mean bad coding coding practice leads to broken apps

Comment: @itadapater thanks for the information on graphics stack! I will be sure not to mix it up with stack that uses the LIFO concept

Comment: @Nicolas When GDI runs out of handle pool on Windows .NET implementation paits red cross to indicate a broken graphics buffer. Many WinForms apps expose this behavior just because developers rely on garbage collector and do not free objects like Fonts, Brushes, Paths, Pens, Regions by hand. The graphics objects pools are limited in size on ALL platforms. The more free ram you have the less frequently GC will engage, so suppose you have a Grid control where you allocate new Brush and Font for every cell - not freeing these objects by hand is a guarantee for painting malfunction in a few minutes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When it comes to `Graphics` there is a simple principle.

If you explicitly create it (e.g. `BuffereImage.createGraphics()`) then dispose of it.

OTOH in `paintComponent(Graphics g)` the instance `g` is provided by the toolkit and disposed of when/if it needs to be.  Doing so in your own code will cause 'unpredictable' rendering.

Comment: I read this from the java doc-For efficiency, programmers should call dispose when finished using a Graphics object only if it was created directly from a component or another Graphics object. I should actually dispose it myself seeeing as the Graphics object was the one who created the graphics context g. I keep the principle in mind. Appreciated the knowledge, Andrew!

Comment: Also discussed here : http://www.coderanch.com/t/540134/Performance/java/Graphics-dispose , same answer.