# Button New Game not working Java

Tags: java, swing, button, frame, actionlistener

Hi im making a project for my studies and im new in java. I need to do a game - Arkanoid. What i wanted to do is a game manu with 2 buttons "New game" and "Quit". Someone from stackoverflow.com rebuild my menu code but it still doesnt work :( After clicking a "New Game" im getting blank frame :(. Probably becouse of `Gra` constructor. How constructor of `Gra` need to look like to make it works with my menu code.
Here is the code (i will paste all `Arkanoid` class code and most important parts of `Gra` class):

Arkanoid class:

```
package arkanoid;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Arkanoid extends JFrame 
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5647459635833443178L;

public Arkanoid() {
    super("Arkanoid");
    setSize(500,400);
    setTitle("Arkanoid BETA");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);

    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    setContentPane(panel);

    panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("New game") {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {     
            panel.removeAll();
            panel.add(new Gra()); //constructor of Gra need to return some Panel i think but i dont know how to do that
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
        }
    }));

   panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Quit") {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {     
            Arkanoid.this.setVisible(false);
        }
    }));
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          Arkanoid frame = new Arkanoid();
          frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Gra class:

```
package arkanoid;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Gra extends JPanel
{
/*some not important variables*/

Pilka pilka;
Paletka paletka;
Cegla cegla_tab[];
Serce serce_tab[];

Timer timer;

public Gra() 
{
    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
    setFocusable(true);

    cegla_tab = new Cegla[liczba_cegiel];
    serce_tab = new Serce[max_zycia];
    //setDoubleBuffered(true);
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduleTask(), 1000, 10);
}

public void addNotify() 
{
    super.addNotify();
    start_gry();
}
public void start_gry() 
{
    pilka = new Pilka();
    paletka = new Paletka();
    /* painting a bricks and lifes for game start */

}
public void koniec_gry()  //end of a game
{
    czas_konca = System.currentTimeMillis();

    gra = 3;
    timer.cancel(); 

}
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paint(g);
    //repaiting ball positions, bricks and paddle

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();
}
private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter 
{
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        paletka.klawisz_puszczony(e);
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        paletka.klawisz_wcisniety(e);
    }
}
class ScheduleTask extends TimerTask 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        if(paletka.czy_pausa()==false)
        {
            pilka.przesun();
            paletka.przesun();
            czy_zderzenie();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}

public void czy_zderzenie() 
{
  //checking a collisions with bricks
}
}
```

Comment: Not all stackoverflow users are polish

Comment: for a JPanel, you override `paintComponent`, not `paint`, and secondly *please* do not dispose of the Graphics that is passed in. You didn't create it, so you really should not dispose of it. Both these items are readily [findable on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118737/how-to-draw-in-jpanel-swing-graphics-java) and [please don't dispose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096836/java-garbage-collection-and-graphics-dispose-method)

Comment: thank you for this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118737/how-to-draw-in-jpanel-swing-graphics-java), fallowing this example i write my own working code. What is more i delete line with `g.dispose();` some one of my friend said that i should do this :/ he was wrong then. Thank you and LunaEques one more time

Answer (score 2):

You need to override paintComponent, not paint.

Also, Gra's constructor does return a JPanel. The constructor will return the object you're constructing, which in this case is a Gra, which is also a JPanel. This is polymorphism at work.

Oh, and as per the comment above, you really shouldn't be disposing of the graphics object.